# Correct Linux command to check the license availability and also the current license users?

Tags: linux, modelsim

I am looking for the Linux command to find the current users of the tool and also the number of license available.

I also need to get the machine details in which the license are being used.

I need to get the following details :

1) total number of licenses
2) number of available licenses
3) machine details in which license is being used.

Comment: What licenses are you talking about?

Comment: Unclear what license manager you are referring to.  Please provide more specifics and context.

Comment: @pitseeker & @ pfranza

modelsim tool :around 20 license installed in common server. all the license were floating license. ie fist come, 1st serve basis.

Comment: This appears to be a "modelsim" specific question and has nothing to do with linux (as you tagged it). You should put all that in the description and also tell us what you have tried already.

Comment: See [ModelSim® SE Installation and Licensing Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/Attachment/modelsim_se_install.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

To list all licenses

```
$ lmstat -a
```

To list a specific license

```
$ lmstat -f <license name>
```